# Mutiple fields search for products magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, search

I need to implement a multiple field search block on my website,
For example a field for brand the next one for model and the last one for year
Help me please if you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the advanced search page, usually at yourstore.com/catalogsearch/advanced/ (or look here for demo https://demo1-m2.mage.direct/catalogsearch/advanced)

You can select which fields are available to search using the product attribute settings. So if you have two product attributes brand and model you just need to ensure "Use in Search" and Advanced search are set to true.

More info here https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/attributes-product.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm not looking for advanced search, I want a search with dependent fields, like those used on cars website( brand, model, year)